# With a Component derivative pointerReleased may never be called after pointerPressed

Tags: codenameone

When a Component derivative is in a scrollable Container after pointerPressed and some scrolling the pointerReleased is never called.

Is this a bug or a feature - and why do You think that way?

Answer (score 0):

There is a special case for buttons which you can leverage by deriving buttons. Events are delivered to the component where they occur. If a release occurs outside of the component it's sent to the component where it occurred as we don't track the original component.

For buttons there is a special pressed and not released case. This will detect such a button in the pointer release code and deliver the event to it.

Comment: This answer is completely off. I assume the behavior is a bug - see https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2647